# While creating the directory I'm getting some sub directories instead?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is the code :

```
namespace Testing
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private string contentDirectory = "";


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            string[] filesContent = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\windows\minidump\");            
            string currentDate = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
            contentDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.LocalUserAppDataPath) + "\\WM_" + currentDate;
            Directory.CreateDirectory(contentDirectory);
        }
```

What I want to get in the end is a directory name like this :

> C:\Users\bout0_000\AppData\Local\Testing\Testing\WM_27-03-13

Instead what im getting now is :

> C:\Users\bout0_000\AppData\Local\Testing\Testing\WM_\23\97\13

Why is that ?

And how can I format the current date to be : `27-03-13 and not 27/03/13` ?

Comment: As a side note, use System.IO.Path.Combine when combining two strings to a path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is that ?

Because the date format of your regional settings uses slashes to separate the parts. When you concatenate that into a file system path, you get into subdirectories.

> And how can i format the current date to be : 27-03-13 and not
>   27/03/13 ? So instead / it will be -

Use `DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yy")`

Answer (score 1):

Specify the format of the string representation of your date time:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yy");
```

See [MSDN - Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) for more info!

Answer (score 1):

To get your desired date string.

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yy");
```